# How many bits are there in a character in a password?

Tags: security, hash, character-encoding, passwords

Trying to understand more about password security.

---

How many bits are there in a character in a password?

For example, say I choose the following password for an account: `4T!h36*^^NQi!u*6m7qFT&3X$L6!x6^&`

How many bits are in this password?

---

Say I choose a different password only composed of alphanumeric characters: `45v9Zu9tvrWTd5ew8qsp9w9d899zf6su`

Is the number of bits influenced by the composition of the password (i.e. whether I include special characters or not) or is it only affected by the length?

---

What would constitute a 256-bit password on a website?

Comment: Which password system? Unix (so C based)? they have ASCII (or maybe just characters, so 8-bit), but this doesn't mean that 256bit password has just so many bits. For security, words counts fewer bits then the count of bits in character. Or are you confusing about certificates? I think you should improve your question, in a more clear way. Maybe you can check the sister site about security: it will help you to understand how the system works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you mean is the amount of information contained in a password, ie. the effort it takes to bruteforce a password compared to a 256Bit key.

You can calculate the amount of possible combinations by
`(number of possible characters)^(length of password)`.

e.g. a 20 character password containing only lowercase letters has 26<sup>20</sup> possible combinations.

From that you can calculate the information contained in the password by log2(number of combinations)

That means a 20 character password containing only lowercase has equal security than a log<sub>2</sub>(26<sup>20</sup>) = 94Bit Key. They are equally hard to bruteforce.

Calculating the bit-strength of a passwort is a good measure of how good a password is.

Important: Please note that this assumes that the password is completely random and doesn't contain any words, ie. every character is statistically independent from each other